# Como puedo agregar eventos al FullCalendar desde una base de datos en Postgres

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, fullcalendar

buenos días.

Mi problema es que tengo un sistema hecho en JSP el cual le agregué el código libre de FullCalendar pero quiero agregar eventos que tengo en una base de datos hecha en Postgres, el problema es que no se como ingresar dichos eventos que recupero desde mi BD en el FullCalendar. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?... Muestro las partes de código importantes:

Clase en java con la cual se hace la consulta a la BD para obtener los datos requeridos que serían, nombre del evento, fecha de inicio y fecha de conclusion):

```
//Creamos nuestros objetos para la comunicacion y ejecucion de codigo SQL
private Connection con;
private Statement stmt, stmt_aux;
private ResultSet rs, rs_aux;
private DataSource ds;

//Constructor    
public Conexion() {
    stmt = null;
    stmt_aux = null;
    con = null;
    rs = null;
    rs_aux = null;
}

//RECUPERA LOS DATOS QUE VAN EN EL CALENDARIO

  public ArrayList getCalendario() throws Exception {
    ArrayList datos = new ArrayList();
    try {
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sp_recuperadatosparacalendariocesip();");
    while (rs.next()) {
      Clase c = new Clase();
      c.setTitle(rs.getString(1));
      c.setDateStart(rs.getString(2));
      c.setTimeStart(rs.getString(3)); 
      c.setDateEnd(rs.getString(4));
      c.setTimeEnd(rs.getString(4)); 
      datos.add(c);
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
   System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage() + " getCalendario =(");
    }
   return datos;
 }
```

Posteriormente en mi archivo JSP recupero los datos obtenidos de la BD:

```
<jsp:useBean id="recuperaDatos" scope="request" class="control.Clase" />

ArrayList calendario = new ArrayList();

recuperaDatos.conecta();
calendario = recuperaDatos.getCalendario();
recuperaDatos.desconecta();

//Aquí esta el script del calendario y le agrego una función para recuperar los datos de los eventos que tengo en  mi ArrayList. 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     events:(function(){
       var data=[];
       for(var r=0;r < <%=calendario.size()%>; r++){
         data.push({
          title: <%=calendario%>[r],
          start: <%=calendario%>[r],
          end: <%=calendario%>[r]
         });
      }
     return data; 
    });

    });

    });

   </script>

   <div id='calendar'style="display: none"></div>
```

El problema con esto es que al agregar el pequeño código de los eventos, se desaparece el calendario y en Netbeans no muestra ningún error, así que no se que pasa o que esta mal. Agradecería su ayuda para ingresar eventos de manera correcta al calendario. Soy nueva en javascript por lo cual su ayuda sería muy útil para mi. De antemano muchas gracias =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listo, logré resolverlo. Con el código que ya tengo. Sólo modifique el Script y queda así:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                events: [
                       <%

                            String t = null;
                            String f_i = null;
                            String h_i = null;
                            String f_i = null;
                            String h_f = null;



                            for (int i = 0; i < calendario.size(); i++){
                                t = ((Clase)calendario.get(i)).getTitle();
                                f_i = ((Clase) calendario.get(i)).getDateStart();
                                h_i = ((Clase) calendario.get(i)).getTimeStart();
                                f_f = ((Clase) calendario.get(i)).getDateEnd();
                                h_f = ((Clase) calendario.get(i)).getTimeEnd();
                        %>


                        {
                        title: "<%=t%>",
                        start: "<%=f_i%>" "T" + "<%=h_i%>",
                        end: "<%=f_f%>" + "T" + "<%=h_f%>"
                        },
                        <%
                           }
                        %>

                ]       
            });
        });

    </script>
```